# Subscribe to refactoring event in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, refactoring

I'm trying to make a plugin for the Eclipse IDE and a part of that requires listening to when the user refactors a code element, mainly just renames. Based on my knowledge I'm assuming that it would rise as an event but I'm having no luck getting answers for this by searching online.
Could anyone suggest what to start reading/where to look more into it?
Thanks!

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ltk/core/refactoring/history/IRefactoringHistoryService.html#addExecutionListener-org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.history.IRefactoringExecutionListener-

Comment: Look at the various `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.xxx` extension points